# Excel: How to get sum from one column where other columns has same name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have an excel of 10k rows,

Hope the following image describe what i wanted.

Tried using =SUM(OFFSET(A1:A32,20,0,10)) but Type is not a fixed number.

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: That is what SUMIFS is for: `=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,E2)` where `E2` has the Type you want to sum.

Comment: @ScottCraner, trying what u've suggested. By the way im new to excel didn't learnt any forumla

Comment: @ScottCraner, I dont know how many types are there (image shown is an example), I want the type also to be printed from forumla (like distict in mysql)

Comment: That is a different question and should have a new post.  In Excel 365 it is easy, `=UNIQUE(A:A)` in older version not so straight forward, but a simple google of `Get Unique List in Excel` will bring up many many examples.

Comment: A pivot table would do this aggregation for you. I.e., the "distinct" and the "sum".

Comment: @ScottCraner got unique result with SUMIFS solved and final forumal is: =SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,E11). where E11, E12, etc has the unique value

Comment: `=SUMIFS(A4:A11,B4:B11,UNIQUE(B4:B11))`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `SUMIF` Function.

```
=SUMIF(A2:A9,D2,B2:B9)
```

You get the desired output below:-

```
Shirt   726.5
Pant    501.48
```